# XML Inflater not seeing any of the views?

Tags: android, xml, view, inflate

First I should prolly ask if it is indeed possible to do what I'm trying to do.

I have a custom RelativeView and it contains 4 TextViews and a button defines in an xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view class="com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.Digital"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/digitalface">
      <TextView android:id="@+id/digi_reading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
      <TextView android:id="@+id/digi_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/> 
      <Button android:id="@+id/digi_grouping"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
      <TextView android:id="@+id/digi_measurement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
      <!-- If a gauge has more than one input types, this is how they would 
      toggle them. -->
      <TextView android:id="@+id/digi_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/digi_reading"
        android:layout_above="@+id/digi_measurement"/>
</view>
```

This I inflated the views into the RelativeLayout class.

```
public void init() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mReadDisplay = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.id.digi_reading, this, true);
            mReadDisplay.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "font/DIGITALDREAM.ttf"));
            mReadDisplay.setTextSize(18f);
        mHeadDisplay = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.id.digi_header, this, true);
            mHeadDisplay.setTextSize(14f);
        mMeasureDisplay = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.id.digi_measurement, this, true);
            mMeasureDisplay.setTextSize(10f);
        mTypeDisplay = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.id.digi_type, this, true);
            mTypeDisplay.setTextSize(10f);
        mGrouping = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.id.digi_grouping, this, true);
            mGrouping.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    }
```

Everything looks good so far, so I run it and get a massive xml crash saying that it can't find my resource. Is it because I embedded it in the custom RelativeLayout?

```
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:8666)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.WorkBench$2$1.onClick(WorkBench.java:64)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:876)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge.<init>(DigitalGauge.java:41)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     ... 19 more
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050000 type #0x12 is not valid
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge.init(DigitalGauge.java:47)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.AppionWidget.<init>(AppionWidget.java:30)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.Gauge.<init>(Gauge.java:13)
02-07 16:23:57.332: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28002):     ... 23 more
```

Thanks for any help
~Aedon

EDIT @ DAN BRESLAU The stack trace:

```
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:8666)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.WorkBench$3$1.onClick(WorkBench.java:106)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:876)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge.<init>(DigitalGauge.java:41)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     ... 19 more
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:8666)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge.init(DigitalGauge.java:45)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.AppionWidget.<init>(AppionWidget.java:30)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.Gauge.<init>(Gauge.java:13)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     ... 23 more
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge.<init>(DigitalGauge.java:41)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     ... 31 more
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:8666)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge.init(DigitalGauge.java:45)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.AppionWidget.<init>(AppionWidget.java:30)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.Gauge.<init>(Gauge.java:13)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     ... 35 more
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.DigitalGauge.<init>(DigitalGauge.java:41)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393):     ... 43 more
02-08 08:52:21.904: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1393): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: B
```

And this is the first part of the class. It has to deal with initializing the layout.

```
public class Digital extends RelativeLayout{
    /*****  *****   *****   *****   *****   *****   *****   *****\
     * BEGIN ALL CONSTANTS AND VARIALBES 
    \*****  *****   *****   *****   *****   *****   *****   *****/
    // Class name for logging purposes
    private final String TAG    =   "Digital";
    /**
     * All of the display types used for the Digital Gauge display
     */
    private TextView mReadDisplay, mHeadDisplay, mMeasureDisplay, mTypeDisplay;
    /**
     * The grouping that the gauge is in. Clear if none. Click-able to reassign
     */
    private Button mGrouping;   
    /** The current type of the gauge the we will display. */
    private int mType = 0;

    public Digital(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void init() {
        Digital mDigital = (Digital)View.inflate(context, R.layout.digital, null);
        mReadDisplay = (TextView)mDigital.findViewById(R.id.digi_reading);
            mReadDisplay.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "font/DIGITALDREAM.ttf"));
            mReadDisplay.setTextSize(18f);
        mHeadDisplay = (TextView)mDigital.findViewById(R.id.digi_header);
            mHeadDisplay.setTextSize(14f);
        mMeasureDisplay = (TextView)mDigital.findViewById(R.id.digi_measurement);
            mMeasureDisplay.setTextSize(10f);
        mTypeDisplay = (TextView)mDigital.findViewById(R.id.digi_type);
            mTypeDisplay.setTextSize(10f);
        mGrouping = (Button)mDigital.findViewById(R.id.digi_grouping);
            mGrouping.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish with a custom view class wrapped around the relative layout?  I'm not sure you need that.

Comment: Just trying to create a small rectangle with a background (the RL) and have have 4 views and button organized inside it. If I don't have the RL, I can't control the layout of the 5 other views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [mreichelt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927919/xml-inflater-not-seeing-any-of-the-views/4927978#4927978) pointed out in a comment, your use of Layout.inflate seems suspicious. You probably want to do something more like this:

```
    // Assume that the XML file from your question (above) is named MyLayoutFile.xml 
    // Digital is your derived layout class
    Digital layout = (Digital) inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyLayoutFile, this, true);

    mReadDisplay = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.digi_reading);
    //...
    mHeadDisplay = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.digi_header);
    //...
    mMeasureDisplay = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.digi_measurement);
```

and so on. Notice especially that the ID passed into `inflater.inflate` is prefixed with `R.layout.`, whereas the ID passed into `findViewById` is prefixed with `R.id.` (Unfortunately, passing the wrong kind of resource identifier will never generate a compile-time error.)

Comment: Just noticed that I screwed up the mapping of the XML to the code when I posted the above. I've edited it; I think it's correct now.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I tried yours and schwiz's answers and as I expected It didn't work. It recursively crashes. I think what I failed to impart clearly is that the TextViews are being defined in the custom RelativeView itself. So I can't place the creation of a RL in the custom RL class. I'm trying to wrap all of these view into one view that is already to go and can be used multiple times. The text view also need to be clickable and have there text change quite frequently.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: "It recursively crashes"... could you show the code and stack trace? As far as I know, `Inflater.inflate` **will not work** the way that you're calling it; so having it crash with this fix may well indicate a completely different problem. Also, have you seen the documentation on creating Compound Controls? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Comment: Ok, placed the trace and what I trace for the class so far. As for the Inflater.inflate I'm not pushing that it will work. That mere fact that I'm asking for help on told me that that it wouldn't :). As for compound controls, I have read it, but I didn't quite understand how to implement my sub views.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: These errors (both the old and the new) are coming from `DigitalGauge.init`, not `Digital.init`. I'd need to see the code for DigitalGauge (Java and XML) to make any progress on this. It might be simple if you open a new question about the new error.

Comment: Above comment should read: "It might be **simpler** if you open a new question..." (can't edit it now.)

Comment: Sorry they are the same thing. I was cutting the 'gauge' part out as I moved it over to SO

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: As you seem to have suspected, I think you should not be loading the custom XML for your Layout class from *within* that Layout class definition. (The Android docs are frustratingly unclear about this.) Have a look at this example: http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/03/android-sdk-loading-layout-and-associating-to-a-class/ . Notice that the custom Layout *extends* `LinearLayout`, but it *uses* `TableLayout` as its top-level container in the XML.

Comment: Haha! Ok thank you for all your help with this, sorry It was so frustrating. And thank you for the example, It is quite clear and helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the first tag as `<merge>`-tag instead of defining your own class again. At least I did it this way a few days ago. Here is more information:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Comment: What am I merging to if I remove the custom class? Just have the custom RL inflate the 5 view on there on in the xml?

Comment: Ok, I read some more of your code. You seem to use inflate a lot and attach your views automatically to your root with the last parameter (true). I guess you should clean this up first. Normally you don't need this here. And you only need to inflate the root layout, not your sub views.

Comment: Ah I see. Then use something like getChild to get all of the other views? I need them to add action listeners to.

Comment: The link you provided is now dead (404). Is there an updated version you could reference?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you only call inflate for the root view.

```
com.android.appionresourcemanager.Widgets.Digital mDigital = (Digital)View.inflate(this, R.layout.mylayout, null);
 mReadDisplay = (TextView)mDigital.findViewById(R.id.digi_reading);
 //....
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for you post, but same issue as I had with Dan Breslau.

Comment: Is `Digital` not extending a `ViewGroup` such as `LinearLayout`?  this could be the only issue I can think of.