# Android Custom View and BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, view, expandablelistview

I want to add a custom view to a group view with a BaseExpandableListAdapter

This is The code:

**The custom view and layout.xml**

```
public class InfoView extends View{
    private EditText nameEditText;
    private EditText descriptionEditText;
    private Spinner goalTypeSpinner;
    private Spinner categorySpinner;



    Button addGoalCategoryButton;
    public InfoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.info_panel, parent);
        nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);

        descriptionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);

        goalTypeSpinner = (Spinner) 
                findViewById(R.id.goalTypeSpinner);

        categorySpinner = (Spinner) 
                findViewById(R.id.categorySpinner);
    }
}
```

infopanel.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/goalTypeSpinner" android:prompt="@string/goalType"
            android:entries="@array/goalTypeList" style="@style/commonText.commonSpinner" >
    </Spinner>
    <TableRow style="@style/commonText.commonTableRow">

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/categorySpinner" style="@style/commonText.commonSpinner.right"
                android:prompt="@string/goalType">
            </Spinner>
            <Button android:id="@+id/newCategoryButton" style="@style/commonText.commonButton"
                android:text="add category" />
    </TableRow> 
    <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEditText" android:hint="@string/nameEditTextHint"
        style="@style/commonText.commonEditText" >
    </EditText>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText" android:hint="@string/descriptionEditTextHint"
        style="@style/commonText.commonTextArea">
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the BaseExpandableListAdapter :

```
..............
InfoView infoView;
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (group.equals(INFO) && child.equals(INFO)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "group INFO(" + group + ")");

            if (infoView == null) {

                // i don't want to recreate everytime 
                // the view so i check if is null         

                infoView = new InfoView(context);
            }

            return infoView;
        }
........
```

The code works (ie doesn't throw any exception) but the view isn't displayed.

Do you know Why ?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to implement getChildView is to use the provided convertView.  Don't keep reference of any Views created in getChildView.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = new InfoView(context);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: i'ts correct ... but i want to mantain a local variale of my view ... because i've other view control on it ,,, like editText and other kind of input controls...  and i need to control if my view is null rather than the convertview

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot missing from the code you've posted: Where is infopanel.xml used? How do you populate InfoView's child views with data? Etc.

But going from what you *have* posted, it looks like you're trying to create what's called a [Compound Control](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound). Such controls (apparently) need to derive from a Layout, such as LinearLayout, that manages the child views appropriately. Deriving from View as you've done would work only if you had added a lot more code to your View class that you haven't shown here -- for example, implementations of `onMeasure` and `onDraw`.

I suggest you read the docs on [Compound Controls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound), if you haven't already.

[gngr44's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437256/gngr44) is also correct -- you shouldn't be trying to reuse an InfoView in that way. Trust the Android code to recycle the views for you, and use the `convertView` if it's not `null`.

Comment: @antonio: I missed it in my first reading, because the code references it as `info_panel`, not `infopanel`. If you're still having problems, you might want to check out my answer to a similar question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927919/xml-inflater-not-seeing-any-of-the-views/4928746#4928746